# authentication with youtube using AccountManager [not work]

Tags: android, youtube-api, accountmanager

I want to create authentication with google account using AccountManager.

I'm using AccountManager to get username and token and I set up my SharedPreferences. 
I create credential, httptransport, and gson factory and I start  Youtube instance, but when i want to create a new playlist, "unfortunately app has stopped working".

code:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
        credential.setAccessToken(authPreferences.getToken().toString());
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new AndroidJsonFactory();
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("radio-info")
                .build();
        PlaylistSnippet playlistSnippet = new PlaylistSnippet();
        playlistSnippet.setTitle("cjg");
        playlistSnippet.setDescription("YouTube API v3");
        Playlist youTubePlaylist = new Playlist();
        youTubePlaylist.setSnippet(playlistSnippet);


        try
        {
            YouTube.Playlists.Insert playlistInsertCommand =
                    youtube.playlists().insert("snippet,status", youTubePlaylist);
            playlistInsertCommand.execute();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

what im doing wrong ? bad auth?

Thanks for answers

edit://

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.radioinfo, PID: 20425
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.radioinfo.AuthActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
            at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
            at pl.poteralski.radioinfo.AuthActivity.doCoolAuthenticatedStuff(AuthActivity.java:105)
            at pl.poteralski.radioinfo.AuthActivity.onCreate(AuthActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: I just used AsyncTask and NetworkOnMainThreadException has gone. App works, but code still not create a new playlist. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should post a new question if you're having a different problem

Comment: [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613215/youtube-api-auth-using-account-manger-not-work)